# How do I convert my coordinates to the limit of geographic region (outer edge)?

Tags: grass-gis, convert, region

I am trying to use [r.in.bin](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/r.in.bin.html). The parameters of north, south, east, and west needs values:
north=float
Northern limit of geographic region (outer edge)
south=float
Southern limit of geographic region (outer edge)
east=float
Eastern limit of geographic region (outer edge)
west=float
Western limit of geographic region (outer edge)

I only have the values for my map, which is in this format:
north: 15N
south: 10N
east: 125E
west: 120E
rows: 6000
cols: 6000

How do I convert them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use gdalinfo to get the boundingbox/region in `float` format.  Looking at your values, I think this is the correct syntax: `north=15 south=10 east=125 west=120`